лексическая сочетаемость

Большинство причин бесплодия современная медицина лечит при
своевременном обращении к врачу.

Могут ли употребляться в данном речевом отрезке слова "лечит" и "большинство причин"?  Нет ли здесь нарушения лексической сочетаемости?

Цитируете или сочиняете?

Нет, это не мой текст. Цитирую)

Причины не лечат,  их устраняют. См Карту слов  https://kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/причина. Можно так записать: Современная медицина предлагает эффективные методы лечения бесплодия в большинстве случаев при своевременном обращении к врачу.

Согласна с вами) Беда в том, что в указанном вами источнике (Карте слов) в качестве нормативного приведён среди прочих вариант «лечить причину»

Надо им написать)  Это явная ошибка, уши режет)  Причина не заболевание,чтобы ее можно было лечить. // Мне кажется, у них не ручная, а машинная обработка текстов. И если кто-то использовал такое сочетание, то оно уже учитывается в Карте.   // Вы пишите адрес участника в сообщении, а то мне не приходит информация ( я здесь не в теме).

Эти слова могут употребляться в данном контексте. Причины бесплодия — различные заболевания. А их именно лечат.

Лексическая сочетаемость слов "лечить", "заболевания", "болезни" очевидна. В данном тексте "лечить причины". Устранять причины, справляться с причинами - годится. Лечить причины - меня смущает)

@Natalya в вашем примере "заболевания" и "причины" выступают синонимами. Не вижу препятствий лечить причины, если причины это болезни
